# Proving a theorem about the average value of a function over a specific region

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, integration, calculus, signal-processing

Let's say transient phenomenon in a function. A [transient phenomenon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transient_(oscillation)) is defined as:

*"A transient event is a short-lived burst of energy in a system caused by a sudden change of state."*

So, for example in the picture below:

[image]

The average value of a function over the region $[0,\infty)$ is given by:

$$\overline{y}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\int_0^ny(t)dt\tag1$$

For the example in the picture the average value is equal to $0$.

> Theorem: If the function $f(t)$ is the sum of two functions $y(t)$ and $z(t)$. And $y(t)$ is the transient part of the function $f(t)$, the average value of the function $f(t)$ (over the region $[0,\infty)$) is given by:
>
> $$\overline{f}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\int_0^nf(t)dt=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\int_0^nz(t)dt\tag2$$

How can I prove that theorem? I've no idea

---

Cheking for a few cases where it does work:

- $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\int_0^n(4+e^{-x}\cos(x))\space dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\int_0^n4\space dx=4\tag3$$
- $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\int_0^n(\sin^2(t)+e^{-4t}(4+\cos(2t+(\pi/989))))\space dt=$$
  $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\int_0^n\sin^2(t)\space
     dt=\frac{1}{2}\tag4$$

Comment: I've added the homework-and-exercises tag. In the future, please use this tag on this type of question.

Comment: @BenCrowell But it is not a homework question. I'm using this theorem in my work, but I do not know if it is true in general!

Comment: The point is that it is a *homework-like* question. It doesn't matter whether it's actual homework or not.

Comment: It might be better for the [math.se]

Comment: @N.Steinle I do not know how to transfer it to there.

Comment: You can just ask it there again, and provide the link to this one saying that you've also asked it here. ANyway, if $f$ is just the sum of $y$ and $z$, then you can split up the integral over $f$ into two integrals, one over $y$ and the other over $z$, where the limit is also distributive. One of those integrals go to zero, no? And then you'll be left with the desired one, I think. Perhaps I've missed something.

Comment: @N.Steinle I think that your reasoning is right (it is the same as mine) but seasoning is not a formal mathematical proof.

Comment: then write it as a formal proof. It takes two lines, like noah shows below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key here is the limit of $n \rightarrow \infty$. The transient part of the function need not necessarily integrate to 0, as in all your exapmles. However, it must, by definition, approach 0 for $t \rightarrow \infty$ (otherwise it would be in the steady state part of the function). And the factor of $1/n$ suppresses any contribution the transient part has for $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Formally we can show it like this
\begin{align}
  \bar{f} &= \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}\int_0^n f(t) dt = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}\int_0^n \left(y(t) + z(t)\right) dt\\
          &= \underbrace{\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}\int_0^n y(t)dt}_{= 0} + \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}\int_0^n z(t)dt = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}\int_0^n z(t)dt
\end{align}

To show that the first term vanishes, we need to investigate $y(t)$ at $t\rightarrow\infty$. Since $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}y(t) = 0$, we must have $|y(t)| < t^{-\epsilon} \enspace\forall t > T$ with $\epsilon > 0$, where $T$ is some large time after which $|y(t)|$ strictly decays. For brevity we assume $\epsilon \neq 1$, since we can always replace it with a value smaller than 1, and the inequality still holds. Integrating gives
\begin{align}
   \int_T^n t^{-\epsilon}dt = \left.\frac{t^{1-\epsilon}}{1-\epsilon}\right|_{t=T}^{n} = \frac{n^{1-\epsilon}}{1-\epsilon} - \frac{T^{1-\epsilon}}{1-\epsilon}
\end{align}
Because we also know that $\left|\int f(t)dt\right| \leq \int |f(t)|dt$, we can write
\begin{align}
    \left|\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}\int_0^n y(t)dt\right| &\leq \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}\int_0^n |y(t)|dt = \underbrace{\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}\overbrace{\int_0^T |y(t)|dt}^{<\infty}}_{=0} + \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}\int_T^n |y(t)|dt\\
&\leq \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n} \int_T^n t^{-\epsilon}dt = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}\frac{n^{1-\epsilon}}{1-\epsilon} - \underbrace{\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}\overbrace{\frac{T^{1-\epsilon}}{1-\epsilon}}^{<\infty}}_{=0}\\
&= \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n^{-\epsilon}}{1-\epsilon} = 0
\end{align}

We implicitly assumed that $y(t)$ is integrable on all bounded intervals of $t$.

Comment: Your answer has my upvote. It is more detailed than mine.